# Python Matplotlib Barplot Questions (xaxis date formatting and colormapping)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

having a couple aesthetic issues...

1. I'm trying to adjust the formatting of the date tick labels of the x-axis so that it only shows the Year and Month values. From what I've found online, I have to use mdates.DateFormatter, but it's not taking effect at all.
2. Colormap. I'd like to gradient the colors of my barplots so that it's redder the more negative, and bluer the more positive the value.

This is what I have right now:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cm as cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('Spectral')

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

basicDF['some_column'].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', rot=75, cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

Thanks guys!

**Reproducible data:**

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=20, freq='m')

blah = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
```